# Can't write string in multiple lines

Tags: php, string, echo, multiline

I'm trying to write in multiple lines with echo and save multiple lines as string, but have little success so far.

I tried `\n`, `\r`, `heredoc/nowdoc,php_eol`... all without success.

I even copied directly from php.net manual.... still get all my strings in one line.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: Show us actual piece of code, its hard to tell anything just in theory, and btw. what was "unsuccessful" output

Comment: Use a richtext editor for your form and store it as HTML is an easy way to get around this if its user data your storing.

Comment: If you look at it in a browser, bear in mind that any linebreak is treated the same as other whitespace. Either apply `nl2br()` before echoing, or wrap `<pre></pre>` around it, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echo outputs in html, hence use of the `<br>` tag would put the text after it onto a new line.

```
Echo "First line <br> Second line <br> Third line";
```

Would output:

First line
Second line
Third line

Comment: Just to clarify, it's a little misleading to say that echo outputs in HTML. Echo just prints data to the standard output stream: how it gets interpreted depends on the context. If you're generating a CSS file, for instance, then echo will output CSS, not HTML.

Comment: This works, tx.
I'm obviously at beginner level, but thought this should be really simple. I saw i can just store this as varible too.